# c - how to create a config object

Tags: c, config

I want to create a config object that can be used anywhere in my c program.

What would be the best practice to do so?

Currently, I have a config.h that looks like this:

```
#define OUTPUT 0
#define OUTPUT_DISPLAY 0
#define OUTPUT_WIDTH 1920
#define OUTPUT_HEIGHT 1080

typedef struct {
        const char *output
        const char *output_display;
        int output_width;
        int output_height;
} config_t;
```

Would I create a config_t instance named config or something in the header file?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You *declare* a global object in the header file:

```
extern config_t global_config;
```

and then *define* it in some suitable .c file:

```
config_t global_config;
```

If you were to *define* the config variable in the header file, the linker would complain that multiple instances of `global_config` exist, as a new instance would get created with each import (assuming your project has multiple .c files).

Answer (score 3):

Create a `config.c` file that you will add to your compilation with the following:

```
#include <config.h> // or "config.h"
config_t config_instance = {
        .output = "default output",
        .output_display = "default display",
};
```

And extern the varaible in your config.h file :

```
extern config_t config_instance;
```

Or better. Let's create a function that will allow access to your config, so we can track and validate changes to it. Create `config.c` like this:

```
#include <config.h> // or "config.h"
static config_t config_instance = {
        .output = "default output",
        .output_display = "default display",
};

const config_t *config_get(void) {
     return &config_instance;
}

int config_set(const config_t *newconfig) {
     if (/* check if newconfig is valid etc. */) {
          return -1; // return error number
      }
      config_instance = *newconfig;
      return 0; // success in changing config
 }
```

and export the functions by adding in your `config.h` file:

```
 const config_t *config_get(void);
 int config_set(const config_t *newconfig);
```